Filtering Calculate in DAX with 2 tables
I am trying to get the below DAX calculation to work.  Right now I'm getting an error on the last filter because it references a different table.  What is the best way to work around this?
CALCULATE(SUM(transactions[AdvancedMD Units]), transactions[Billing Code] IN {"97153", "97154", "97155", "97156", "97151", "97152"}, transactions[date_of_service] >= 'auth records'[start_date])
I tried to use filtering on the card itself in PowerBI, but since each client has a different start date, that didn't work.
A sample would be LS has 4 units of 97151 on 05/26/2024, 6 units of 97153 on 6/03/2024.  The authorization started on 6/01/2024.  I only want the 6 units after that date to show up in the Sum.

It would be easier to help if you could post a diagram of the model but maybe try wrap transactions in RELATED() or if it has an inactive relationship try USERELATIONSHIP()

pls provide some sample data and expected output

I did add some sample data and output.  Both the transactions table and the auth records table are related to the date table, but not each other which makes the related function harder to use.

Try using this measure:
SumUnits = 
 VAR currentClient = MAXX(Transactions, [ClientID]) //Gets the current Client's ID
 RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM(Transactions[AdvancedMD Units]), //Sums the Units
    FILTER(Transactions, 
        VAR clientStartDate = LOOKUPVALUE('Auth Records'[Start_Date], 'Auth Records'[ClientID], currentClient) //No relationship between Auth Records and Transactions, LOOKUPVALUE is used instead of RELATE
        RETURN Transactions[Date_of_Service] >= clientStartDate && //Compares the Client Start Date to Transaction Start Date
        Transactions[Billing Code] IN {"97153", "97154", "97155", "97156", "97151", "97152"} //Original measure provided
        )
    )

The measure takes the client id from the Transaction table and searches the Auth Records for the Start Date using LOOKUPVALUE(). Then uses that value to filter the Transaction Date_of_Service column.

Sample Data used:
Auth Records



ClientID
Start_Date




LS
2024-06-01


AB
2024-05-15



Transaction



TransactionID
ClientID
Billing Code
AdvancedMD Units
Date_of_Service




1
LS
97151
4
2024-05-26


2
LS
97153
6
2024-06-03


3
LS
97154
5
2024-06-15


4
AB
97155
3
2024-06-20




it is giving me an error saying syntax for return is incorrect.

I edited my answer to correct this. Please try now.

The error is gone now, and it does work for those with just one authorization.  However, those that had a previous authorization that has expired and are on a new one, it doesn't work.

I'm sorry, but having multiple/expired authorizations was not described in your initial question. For a better understanding, can you please provide a table of some sample data and expected output?
